# Getting Clickonce to use more recent .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have a Clickonce application that is targeting .NET 3.5.  When I install on a Windows machine with .NET 3.5 installed, it works fine.  However, if I remove .NET 3.5 via Add/Remove Windows Features, and install .NET 4.5 manually, my Clickonce application gives an error: "Unable to install or run the application.  The application requires that assembly WindowsBase version 3.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first."  Even though the ClickOnce is targeting 3.5, shouldn't it be able to run against the .NET 4.5 Runtime if it exists?  How can I configure my Clickonce application to run in this environment?

Comment: It is covered well [in TFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517334.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't remove .NET 3.5. Install .NET 4.5 over .NET 3.5